# What is the best way to parse all the URLs out of a string of HTML?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm writing a web crawler in Node for fun over the next couple weeks. In my prototype, I was using jsdom to jquerify the page, then searching for all the anchors and adding the `href`s to my crawl list. I realized that I could potentially find a lot more URLs if I just parsed any URL out of the source (URLs in text, for example). I'm wondering if there's any good javascript libraries out there to do this using regex or otherwise.

As a side note: Is this a bad idea?

**Update:**

Although I originally selected Chris' answer below I was a bit trigger happy as is turns out. Unfortunately I didn't end up using node.io. I found it to be a little bloated and it doesn't really focus on what I was attempting to do. At the moment I'm using soupselect + htmlparser to grab the href values of any anchors on the page and I'm happy with this solution for the time being.

Comment: @pst, I'm not trying to parse HTML (there are many tools to do that already). I'm trying to extract URLs from a string of HTML

Comment: @pst Read the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2e9c17f8-7ed4-465a-b51f-4efe30e0e7bb/view-source). Enlightening.

Comment: Actually, you might find more URLs if you extracted them from the DOM, as you indicated.  This is because a lot of sites try to obfuscate their code and create dynamic links.  Generally, when you do something like this, you want to do some sort of spidering, using Perl, or some other server-side language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [node.io](https://github.com/chriso/node.io), it's an excellent scraping and processing framework for node.js.

Or, it's also possible to use [YUI3](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/nodejs-yui3/) to parse and manipulate the an HTML document from node.

Comment: Awesome. Bonus points for recommending node.io. Thanks, Chris!

Answer (score 1):

When looking for URLs, I use this regex: `/(https?:\/\/)([^.\/]+(?:\.[^.\/]+)+)(\/.*)/`

You then have sub-patterns:

1. Protocol
2. Domain
3. Path

Not sure how well it'd work for a crawler, but it's never failed me yet.

Comment: Wouldn't that completely ignore any non-absolute URLs?

Comment: As I said, not sure how well it'd work for a crawler. But most URLs in text would be absolute, I think. Since that's what the question was asking, I figured it'd be fine. As for ftp, that's not something I've used in a URL before so I didn't include it. Replacing `https?` with `(?:https?|ftp)` would do the trick.